# merging C# code with roslyn: comment disappears

Tags: c#, roslyn

Scenario: I'm trying to use Roslyn to merge a set of C# source fragments into a single code fragment.

Issue: when parsing different classes with a leading comment, the comment above the first class (`SomeClass` in the example) is not preserved. For the second class (`AnotherClass`), the comment IS preserved...

The code below demonstrates the issue. Use this in a console program (& install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp nuget package)

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;

namespace roslyn01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = new[]
            {
               "// some comment\r\nclass SomeClass {}",
               "// another comment\r\nclass AnotherClass {}",
            };

            // parse all input and collect members
            var members = new List<MemberDeclarationSyntax>();
            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(item);
                var compilationUnit = (CompilationUnitSyntax)syntaxTree.GetRoot();
                members.AddRange(compilationUnit.Members);
            }

            // assemble all members in a new compilation unit
            var result = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit()
                .AddMembers(members.ToArray())
                .NormalizeWhitespace()
                .ToString();

            var expected = @"// some comment
class SomeClass
{
}

// another comment
class AnotherClass
{
}";

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            // the assert fails; the first comment ('// some comment') is missing from the output
            Debug.Assert(expected == result);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ToString()` instead of `ToFullString()` when transforming `CompilationUnitSyntax` to `string`. `ToString()` returns a string removing leading and trailing trivia (including comments), but `ToFullString()` doesn't remove this trivia. You can see it in the code documentation:

```
//
// Description:
//     Returns the string representation of this node, not including its leading and
//     trailing trivia.
//
// Returns:
//     The string representation of this node, not including its leading and trailing
//     trivia.
//
// Comments:
//     The length of the returned string is always the same as Span.Length
public override string ToString();

//
// Description:
//     Returns full string representation of this node including its leading and trailing
//     trivia.
//
// Returns:
//     The full string representation of this node including its leading and trailing
//     trivia.
//
// Comments:
//     The length of the returned string is always the same as FullSpan.Length
public virtual string ToFullString();
```